# pointers in golang json unmarshalling

Tags: api, web-services, go

I'm trying to unmarshal a web service response using the below command and it works fine.

```
bodyBytes, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(response.Body)
bodyString := string(bodyBytes)
err = json.Unmarshal([]byte(bodyString), &output)
fmt.Println(&output)
```

When I use the pointer variable '&output' it works fine ie; the outputs are displayed properly.

but when I try to use the variable directly without &(ampersand), the outputs do not look good.

```
bodyBytes, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(response.Body)
bodyString := string(bodyBytes)
err = json.Unmarshal([]byte(bodyString), output)
fmt.Println(output)
```

What is the difference between these 2 variable - pointer vs normal variable while unmarshalling?

```
var output core.ApiData
```

The output is a type struct to match the apidata output.

Comment: A pointer will only affect other goroutines if they all have pointers to the same value. Make sure they don't and it will work fine.

Comment: @Adrian: THanks, How can I create dynamic variables in golang? The &output variable that is passed to the function should be created dynamically based on the number of goroutines created using the range parameter.

Comment: What do you mean by "dynamic variable"?

Comment: ignore it, was lil bit confused initially..thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is because the `Unmarshal` function takes the `output` struct and populates it with the data. If you do not pass a pointer, it will take a copy of your struct and fill it, after which you don't have access to it any more. If you pass a pointer, the `output` struct behind the pointer will be populated and remain available.

Answer (score 3):

As you can see, `json.Unmarshal` does not return a value, so if you passed a value instead of a pointer, it would have no way to work properly as it would fill its copy of the interface it takes as parameter.

The way it works is that you pass a pointer to the structure you want to fill, and `json.Unmarshal` will populate it directly using the pointer.

See [the documentation](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Unmarshal) for more details.

> Unmarshal parses the JSON-encoded data and stores the result in the **value pointed to by v**. If v is nil or not a pointer, Unmarshal returns an InvalidUnmarshalError.